# Wordpress shows different upload_max_filesize than php.ini setting

Tags: uploads, php.ini

I have php.ini files in the following directories of my WordPress installation:

- /wp-admin
- /wp-content
- / (where there wp-config.php lies)

In all of them I set `upload_max_filesize = 640M;` - **640MB** is the maximum value that is allowed by my provider in my package (I called).

```
memory_limit = 268435456;
post_max_size = 67108864;
upload_max_filesize = 640M;
```

I did NOT configure an upload_max_filesize in wp-config.php or in .htaccess. I confirmed this value with `phpinfo()` and with `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')`.

Nonetheless, WordPress displayes **64 MB** as maximum on the media upload page and on the WooCommerce status page.

I am utterly puzzled. I checked every post on stack but I couldn't find an answer to that dissonance. Help would be much appreciated.

[image: upload page]
[image: WC status]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED:

I figured out the following by playing with the numbers in the php.ini in /wp-admin:

The add upload page in the admin area seems to always **display the lower value** of either `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`.

In my case, `post_max_size` was lower than `upload_max_filesize` which is the reason for "Maximum size of files for uploads" not displaying the 640MB but 64MB.

I suppose this has to do with this: see [php.net docs](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) as:

> post_max_size integer
>       Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size.

Comment: If you add other things to your question update it, this is not answer.

Comment: Why is this not an answer? It explains why the values from my questions do not match.

Answer (score -1):

`upload_max_filesize` for uploading file from multipart-form. Other hand `post_max_size` is posted size from form. (input textarea etc). So i prefer, create php file in root directory such as php.php and write phpinfo for real compare.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Comment: As I said in my question, I already did read the entries of `phpinfo()`.

Comment: ok this is only for healthy comparison. I explain different between upload_max_filesize and post_max_size

Comment: I am sorry but your answer is not a good one in my eyes. It is difficult to understand due to missing practical context and and it lacks external sources.

Comment: OK you are hero :) I explain to you difference between upload_max_filesize and post_max_size so my answer is clear, if you want to external resources just search in php.net. I want to help you you give me downvote. Thank you

Comment: Why? Irony is utterly useless on Stack IMHO. It was not me who downvoated, btw.